# Filling Area between two Bezier Curves with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

I would like to fill an area between two Bezier curves.

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, shapes}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[name path=A] (1cm,4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,1.2cm) and (1.5cm,1cm) .. (10cm,0.4cm);
 \draw[name path=B] (1cm,-4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,-1.2cm) and (1.5cm,-1cm) .. (10cm,-0.4cm);


 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I've already tried it with `\filldraw`, but unfortunately this keeps filling the wrong side.
I've also considered the possibility to use `\addplot[brown!50] fill between[of=A and B];` , but I struggeled to add the Bezier Curves with the `\addplot` command.

Also I'd like to have a opacity flow from left to right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill area between two lines tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288025/fill-area-between-two-lines-tikz)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE I believe your question has been answered on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288025/fill-area-between-two-lines-tikz

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Thanks for your answer! But how can I draw Bezier curves using "\addplot"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using any additional libraries, you may just use the clipping function (and store the path in a macro for convenience):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\pathA}{(1cm,4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,1.2cm) and (1.5cm,1cm) .. (10cm,0.4cm)}
  \newcommand{\pathB}{(1cm,-4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,-1.2cm) and (1.5cm,-1cm) .. (10cm,-0.4cm)}

  \begin{scope}
   \clip \pathA -- (10cm,-4cm) -- (1cm,-4cm) -- cycle; 
   \fill[orange!50] \pathB -- (10cm,4cm) -- (1cm,4cm) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}

  \draw \pathA;
  \draw \pathB;

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am wondering it you are referring to the trick discussed [here](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4153/wie-kann-ich-die-flache-zwischen-mehreren-pfaden-fullen/4161) and used [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302531/121799), where it is described how the intersection library can be used to essentially combine two paths to a new path. Using this trick, one can actually get the desired filling in two steps. This leads to the code

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302531/121799
% and http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4153/wie-kann-ich-die-flache-zwischen-mehreren-pfaden-fullen/4161s
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
  \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
  \draw [name path=A] (1cm,4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,1.2cm) and (1.5cm,1cm) ..
     (10cm,0.4cm);
  \draw [name path=B] 
    (1cm,-4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,-1.2cm) and (1.5cm,-1cm)
     .. (10.cm,-0.4cm);
  \path [name path=C] (1cm,4cm) -- (1cm,-4cm); 
  \path [name path=D] (10cm,-0.4cm) -- (10cm,0.4cm); 
  \path [%draw,line width=3,blue,
    name path=AandC,
    intersection segments={
        of=A and C,
        sequence={A1[reverse] -- B1}
    }];
  \path [%draw,line width=3,purple,
    name path=BandD,
    intersection segments={
        of=B and D,
        sequence={A0 -- B1[reverse]}
   }];

  \pgfonlayer{pre main}
  \fill [
    blue!40!white,
    intersection segments={
        of=AandC and BandD,
        sequence={A1 -- B1},
    }
  ];
  \endpgfonlayer

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**WARNING**: I kept your path labels, but want to draw your attention to the fact that `A` and `B` in `sequence={A1[reverse] -- B1}` and `sequence={A1 -- B1}` does **not** refer to these paths. Rather, `A` and `B` refer to the two paths that are being married. (What `[reverse]` does is more intuitive.) The numbers after `A` and `B` (seem to) refer to the part that should be put in this path, e.g. `A0` is the stretch of the first path before the intersection and `A1` is the stretch after. Once you know this, this might be the most straightforward way of combining paths, and use those for shading etc. (Of course, in order to make this work, I needed to add the vertical paths at boundaries, `C` and `D`.)

Answer (score 3):

(I know this is an old post but it's just resurfaced ...)

I'm a bit surprised that the following solution hasn't been suggested already: simply join the paths with lines and shade (or fill) the region thus defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417970/86}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

\shade[left color=brown!50]
(1cm,4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,1.2cm) and (1.5cm,1cm) .. (10cm,0.4cm)
--
(10cm,-0.4cm) .. controls (1.5cm,-1cm) and (1.3cm,-1.2cm)  .. 
(1cm,-4cm) -- cycle;

 \draw (1cm,4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,1.2cm) and (1.5cm,1cm) .. (10cm,0.4cm);
 \draw (1cm,-4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,-1.2cm) and (1.5cm,-1cm) .. (10cm,-0.4cm);


 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

The only down side of this is defining the paths twice.  In this case, they aren't very complicated so that doesn't seem a hardship.  If that is a problem, then the following uses [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) to save and reuse the paths.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417970/86}
 \usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{spath3}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

% Save the paths, but don't draw them
 \path[spath/save=A] (1cm,4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,1.2cm) and (1.5cm,1cm) .. (10cm,0.4cm);
 \path[spath/save=B] (1cm,-4cm) .. controls (1.3cm,-1.2cm) and (1.5cm,-1cm) .. (10cm,-0.4cm);

\shade[
  left color=brown!50,
  spath/use=A % set the initial path to be A
]
-- (spath cs:B 1) % add a straight line to the end of B
[spath/use={B,reverse,weld}] % append path B, reversing it, and welding it
% to make a single path for shading
-- cycle % cycle back to the start
;

\draw[spath/use=A]; % draw path A
\draw[spath/use=B]; % draw path B

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Both of these produce the following:

[image: Shaded region between two paths]

Comment: Good to know that `spath3` enhances `path` operations of TikZ. You wrote that there’s another document which focusses on usage (of `spath3`)" in https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/spath3_code.pdf . Where is it?

Comment: @BlackMild  Replace `spath3_code.pdf` with `spath3.pdf`, so with the ctan mirror that you link to it is: https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3/spath3.pdf

Comment: Thanks! just notice that in https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spath3, one don't see `spath3.pdf`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I'll try to get that fixed next update.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you want is filling with given left color and given right color. For TikZ, with simplifying `path` operations, we use a small trick to do that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\pathA{(1,4) .. controls (1.3,1.2) and (1.5,1) .. (10,0.4)}
\def\pathB{(1,-4) .. controls (1.3,-1.2) and (1.5,-1) .. (10,-0.4)}

% this is a small trick: clip a bigger region to fill       
\begin{scope}
\clip \pathA -- (10,-4) -- (1,-4) -- cycle; 
\fill[left color=orange,right color=orange!50] \pathB -- (10,4) -- (1,4) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
        
\draw[blue] \pathA;
\draw[red] \pathB;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For Asymptote, with many `path` operations, this is straight to do that: `reverse` to reverse a path; `relpoint` to pick a point on a path. To fill with an uniform color, use `fill(mypath,orange);`. There are several other kinds of filling: `axialshade`, `radialshade`, `gouraudshade`, `tensorshade`, `functionshade` see [here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote.pdf).

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
path pA=(1,4) .. controls (1.3,1.2) and (1.5,1) .. (10,0.4);
path pB=(1,-4) .. controls (1.3,-1.2) and (1.5,-1) .. (10,-0.4);
// path pB=yscale(-1)*pA;    // <<< also works!
path mypath=pA--relpoint(pB,1)--reverse(pB)--cycle;

// fill with uniform color
//fill(mypath,orange);

// fill with left and right color
pen leftpen=green;
pen rightpen=.1green+white;
axialshade(mypath,leftpen,(0,0),rightpen,(10,0));

draw(pA,blue);
draw(pB,red);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```